# How to run OpenOCD on CLion with custom parameters?

Tags: clion, openocd

I would like to run the OpenOCD script in CLion with `tcl_port` enabled.

It looks like they hardcoded this into the plugin https://github.com/elmot/clion-embedded-arm/blob/master/src/xyz/elmot/clion/openocd/OpenOcdComponent.java#L79 does anyone have an idea how to override this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like parameters in the CFG file are not overwritten. So setting `tcl_port 6666` works for me.